# Build FixedDocument without blocking UI

Tags: wpf, async-await

I'm generating a document for [DocumentViewer](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.controls.documentviewer(v=vs.110).aspx). It's slow, so I want to free the UI thread. Using async/await I get an exception saying, "The calling thread must be STA". I believe I need to marshall the values passed/returned with the UI thread, but I can't seem to make it work. I've tried Dispatcher.Invoke in various ways.

Anyone know how to do this using async/await?

Here's a slim, working example you can paste into a fresh WPF project (WpfApp1):

```xml
<Window x:Class="WpfApp1.MainWindow"
        xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
        xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
        xmlns:d="http://schemas.microsoft.com/expression/blend/2008"
        xmlns:mc="http://schemas.openxmlformats.org/markup-compatibility/2006"
        xmlns:local="clr-namespace:WpfApp1"
        mc:Ignorable="d"
        Title="MainWindow" Height="350" Width="525"
        DataContext="{Binding RelativeSource={RelativeSource Self}}">
    <DocumentViewer Document="{Binding Document}"/>
</Window>
```

```cs
public partial class MainWindow : Window, INotifyPropertyChanged
{
    public MainWindow()
    {
        InitializeComponent();
        RebuildDocument(); // Called various places
    }

    public double Length { get; set; } = 100;

    FixedDocument document;
    public FixedDocument Document
    {
        get { return document; }
        set { if (document == value) return; document = value; OnPropertyChanged(); }
    }

    async void RebuildDocument()
    {
        Document = await GenerateDocument(Length);
    }

    private static async Task<FixedDocument> GenerateDocument(double length)
    {
        return await Task.Run(() =>
        {
            // Dummy work
            return new FixedDocument() {
                Pages = { new PageContent() { Child = new FixedPage() {
                        Width = length, Height = length,
                        Children = { new TextBlock() { Text = "dummy page" }}}}}};
        });
    }

    public event PropertyChangedEventHandler PropertyChanged;
    void OnPropertyChanged([CallerMemberName] string propertyName = null)
    { PropertyChanged?.Invoke(this, new PropertyChangedEventArgs(propertyName)); }
}
```

Comment: The problem has nothing to do with `async`/`await`. The problem is that the body of `GenerateDocument` MUST run in an STA Thread. As those are UI Elements being instantiated. Try to use an MVVM approach.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I can think of at least two approaches:

- build your `FixedDocument` inside a background task on the UI thread, while yielding extensively on the innermost loop (and observing the cancellation, too):

  ```
  private static async Task<FixedDocument> GenerateDocument(double length, CancellationToken token = default(CancellationToken))
  {
      var doc = new FixedDocument();
      while (!complete)
      {
          token.ThrowIfCancellationRequested();
          // ...
          doc.Children.Add(anotherChild)
          // ...
          // yield to process user input as often as possible
          await System.Windows.Threading.Dispatcher.Yield(System.Windows.Threading.DispatcherPriority.Input);
      }
  }
  ```
- Build it on a new worker WPF thread (as `FixedDocument` is a `DispatcherObject` and requires a `Dispatcher` loop), serialize it as XAML there and then deserialize it into a new instance of `FixedDocument` on your original UI thread. I'm not sure if *direct deserialization* would be fast enough to not block the UI thread in your case, but at least there's [`XamlReader.LoadAsync`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.markup.xamlreader.loadasync(v=vs.110).aspx) that you should be able to call asynchronously without blocking. 
  Here's a complete proof-of-concept code (cancellation logic skipped for brevity):

  ```
  private async Task<FixedDocument> GenerateDocumentAsync(double length)
  {
      System.IO.Stream streamIn;
      using (var worker = new DispatcherThread())
      {
          streamIn = await worker.Run(() =>
          {
              var doc = new FixedDocument()
              {
                  Pages = { new PageContent() { Child = new FixedPage() {
                  Width = length, Height = length,
                  Children = { new TextBlock() { Text = "dummy page" }}}}}
              };

              var streamOut = new System.IO.MemoryStream();
              XamlWriter.Save(doc, streamOut);
              return streamOut;
          });
      }

      streamIn.Seek(0, System.IO.SeekOrigin.Begin);
      var xamlReader = new XamlReader();
      var tcs = new TaskCompletionSource<bool>();
      AsyncCompletedEventHandler loadCompleted = (s, a) =>
      {
          if (a.Error != null)
              tcs.TrySetException(a.Error);
          else
              tcs.TrySetResult(true);
      };
      xamlReader.LoadCompleted += loadCompleted;
      try
      {
          var doc = xamlReader.LoadAsync(streamIn);
          await tcs.Task;
          return (FixedDocument)doc;
      }
      finally
      {
          xamlReader.LoadCompleted -= loadCompleted;
      }
  }
  ```

  ---

  ```
  public class DispatcherThread: IDisposable
  {
      readonly Thread _dispatcherThread;
      readonly TaskScheduler _taskScheduler;

      public DispatcherThread()
      {
          var tcs = new TaskCompletionSource<TaskScheduler>();

          _dispatcherThread = new Thread(() =>
          {
              var dispatcher = Dispatcher.CurrentDispatcher;
              dispatcher.InvokeAsync(() =>
                  tcs.SetResult(TaskScheduler.FromCurrentSynchronizationContext()));
              Dispatcher.Run();
          });

          _dispatcherThread.SetApartmentState(ApartmentState.STA);
          _dispatcherThread.IsBackground = false;
          _dispatcherThread.Start();

          _taskScheduler = tcs.Task.Result;
      }

      public void Dispose()
      {
          if (_dispatcherThread.IsAlive)
          {
              Run(() => 
                  Dispatcher.CurrentDispatcher.BeginInvokeShutdown(DispatcherPriority.Send));
              _dispatcherThread.Join();
          }
      }

      public Task Run(Action action, CancellationToken token = default(CancellationToken))
      {
          return Task.Factory.StartNew(action, token, TaskCreationOptions.None, _taskScheduler);
      }

      public Task<T> Run<T>(Func<T> func, CancellationToken token = default(CancellationToken))
      {
          return Task.Factory.StartNew(func, token, TaskCreationOptions.None, _taskScheduler);
      }

      public Task Run(Func<Task> func, CancellationToken token = default(CancellationToken))
      {
          return Task.Factory.StartNew(func, token, TaskCreationOptions.None, _taskScheduler).Unwrap();
      }

      public Task<T> Run<T>(Func<Task<T>> func, CancellationToken token = default(CancellationToken))
      {
          return Task.Factory.StartNew(func, token, TaskCreationOptions.None, _taskScheduler).Unwrap();
      }
  }
  ```

Comment: The problem isn't an async/await problem. The problem is that the code isn't MVVM. `PageContent` : `UIElement`. Therefore cannot be instantiated within a background thread. The exception comes from the `Task.Run`.

Comment: @Aron, being highly involved in document processing and visualization, I doubt you'd get far away trying to apply MVVM pattern to a *large and complex* `FixedDocument`. While the document object itself can (and should) be a biddable property of a ViewModel, you woudn't want doing this for its individual `UIElement` child object, unless it's a very simple document. The UI experience would be terrible if you apply MVVM to a the whole object model of a large XAML document.

Comment: And `FixedDocument` can perfectly well be instantiated on a background thread (as long as it's a WPF Dispatcher thread, as mentioned in the answer). It just can't be used across different threads (the way @Vimes tries doing it), but it can be cloned via serialization.

Comment: I would hardly call a WPF Dispatcher thread a background thread. More a Secondary UI Thread. There are of course examples of code out there where an application runs multiple UI Threads, but of course, here be dragons.

Comment: Turns out, my problem wasn't page count, but that individual elements in the document (Viewport3D's) took 2s to construct. Yield is acceptable if I do it between constructing each one. I got a similar approach to the second solution working: rendering the slow elements to RenderTargetBitmaps which, once frozen, can pass the thread boundary. I'd like to switch to the document serialize/deserialize approach, if I have time. Should work well, as long as LoadAsync does what we expect.

Comment: @Vimes, glad if it helped. I'd be interested to know if `xamlReader.LoadAsync` was actually helpful. I suspect it'd only be different in what it uses async I/O stream APIs.

Comment: Me too. I'll be sure to post back if I figure it out.